# Detect when user reaches maxBounds using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet to show an interactive map to our users. 
We want to let them browse through a limited area, and inform them they have to subscribe in case they want to see something too far away (using a pop up or equivalent).

So far I have seen that Leaflet supports a *[maxBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-setmaxbounds)* option. 
This is a good start that lets me prevent users to see larger areas.

Now I would like to be able to detect a maxBounds 'event' to show the user a pop up.

I have been looking into the Leaflet source code, but couldn't find an obvious way to do it.

so far I have found that the maxBounds option is fed into the **setView** method. 
This method itself uses the **_limitCenter** method to define the center. 
This goes a few levels deeper, down to the **_getBoundsOffset** method that finally uses the bounds.

```
    _getBoundsOffset: function (pxBounds, maxBounds, zoom) {
    var projectedMaxBounds = toBounds(
            this.project(maxBounds.getNorthEast(), zoom),
            this.project(maxBounds.getSouthWest(), zoom)
        ),
        minOffset = projectedMaxBounds.min.subtract(pxBounds.min),
        maxOffset = projectedMaxBounds.max.subtract(pxBounds.max),

        dx = this._rebound(minOffset.x, -maxOffset.x),
        dy = this._rebound(minOffset.y, -maxOffset.y);

    return new Point(dx, dy);
},
```

The closest I could find so far would be to hook into the [moveend](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-moveend) event and check whether the center is out of my bounds manually. 
However, it seems like this would be redundant with what leaflet is already doing.

Is there a better to leverage leaflet to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Additional question : this sounds like it could be a useful feature? Am I the only one thinking that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if your defined bounds contain the map bounds. As long as the map bounds are inside the defined bounds, this will do nothing:

```
var myBounds = L.latLngBounds(...)

map.on('move moveend zoomend', function(){
    if (!myBounds.contains(map.getBounds())) {
        // Display popup or whatever
    }
});
```

> it seems like this would be redundant with what leaflet is already doing.

Don't worry about that. The overhead is negligible for this use case.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. That's kinda what I had in mind. Guess I was trying to DRY too much :). Thanks

Comment: Many thanks. Have had a failure of a week and this allowed me to kick at least one goal without making a further mess.